# Monte Carlo in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, variance

When I try to run this program:

```
n = 10000;

Constant = 5.0;
A = 10; 
B = 5;
C = 1.335;
Drand = (0.02*randn(1,n)) + 0.242*ones(1,n);
Erand = (0.005*randn(1,n)) + 0.536*ones(1,n); 
P = (Constant*A*B*(1.0/C))*(Drand.*(1.0-Erand.));
plot(P);
```

I get this error:

> Error: "identifier" expected, ")" found.

where the variances are `0.02` and `0.005`, and Mean are `0.242` and `0.536`, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `.` too much on the second last line. It should be:

```
 P = (Constant*A*B*(1.0/C))*(Drand.*(1.0-Erand));
```

Also, your variances aren't actually `0.02` and `0.005`. Think about it ;-)

Comment: Christan Reimer,Thanks you very much for your kind help and information.